# VBA loop, repeat formula through column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, repeat

I am trying to replicate in VBA the simple function in excel which allows you to repeat a function through an entire column, and stops when the columns on the side are empty. Specifically, I want to repeat an if - else if function for the entire relevant part of the column

Here's an attempt which does not really work

```
Sub RepeatIfElseif
    Range("A1").Select
    If selection > 0 Then
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "X"
        Range("A1").Select
    ElseIf selection <= 0 Then
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
    End If
    Range("B1").Select
    selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B134")
```

Is there any way I can do it with a loop?

Answer (score 1):

### You do not need to loop to drop formulas in. You just need to know where the last row is!

---

Pick a column that is most likely to represent your last row (I am using `Column A` in my example) and then you can dynamically *drop-down* your equation in one line without the loop.

The below will fill in the equation `A2 + 1` in `Column B` starting from 2nd row (*assuming you have a header row*) down to the last used row in `Column A`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Formula_Spill()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update sheet!
Dim LR As Long

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<-- Update column!

ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).Formula = "=A2+1" '<-- Update formula!

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a loop, you can use something like the code below:

```
For i = 1 To 134
    If Range("A" & i).Value > 0 Then
        Range("B" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "X"
    Else
        Range("B" & i").FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
    End If
Next I
```

It can be done without a loop, something like:

```
Range("B1:B134").Formula = "=IF(A1>0," & Chr(34) & "X" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Y" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Not sure what formula you are trying to achieve with `.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to improve my English, I swear...

I would do something like this:

```
dim row as long
dim last_row as Long

last_row = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For row = 1 to last_row
    If Range("A" & row).Value > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = "X"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = "Y"
    End If
Next row
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear that.